# wp_reset_postdata() does not work as expected

Tags: wp-query

In my theme I want to display thumbnail and title of posts of a certain category (ID=1). On click of the thumbnail the post with content,... should be shown.
Since I added the `wp_query` part for the category filtering it always displays *all* posts of the the respective category if I click on one post.
I already added `wp_reset_postdata()` and `wp_reset_query()` but it seems to have no effect.
What else can I do to limit the displaying to the clicked post only and not the whole query?

index.php

```
<?php
        $general_post = new WP_query();
        $general_post->query('cat=1');
        if($general_post->have_posts()) {
            while($general_post->have_posts()) {
                $general_post->the_post();
                get_template_part('content', get_post_format());
            }
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

template file:

```
//template for preview on index
        <?php if (is_home() ) { ?>
                <div>
                    <a href=<?php echo get_permalink();?>><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(300,600)); ?>
                    <header>
                        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title()?></h1>
                    </header>
                    </a>
                </div>
        <?php }
        ?>

//template for whole post
        <?php if (!is_home() ) { ?>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>>
            <?php the_title()?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
             //....
        <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this should be your main loop, the preferable way to modify the main loop is to use the `pre_get_posts` filter. For a secondary, it's okay to use WP_Query, but you're setting query arguments the wrong way. WP_Query expects an array of arguments.

```
$args = array(
    'cat' => 1
);
$general_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

You can read more about WP_Query [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).